Oracle Apex Server-side Code do not set item
I want to make simple region: input field, button to send request to DB and read-only field to display result.

Here are the PL/SQL Code:
begin
  select
  edrpou || '; ' || nameorg || '; ' || short_name || '; ' || address || '; ' || boss
  into :P206_SEARCH_RESULT
  from dual
  left join (
    select * from (
      select
      trim(d.edrpou) edrpou,
      trim(d.nameorg) nameorg,
      trim(d.short_name) short_name,
      trim(d.address) address,
      trim(d.boss) boss,
      d.date_d,
      max(d.date_d) over (partition by trim(d.edrpou)) max_date
      from edrpou_ d
      where trim(d.edrpou) = :P206_EDRPOU_SEARCH and trim(d.short_name) is not null and d.isactual = 1
    ) e
    where e.date_d = e.max_date
  ) on 1=1;
end;

Item P206_SEARCH_RESULT is null after button click. I checked query, it's working in Developer.

Looks fine to me. I suggest you try reproducing this with the sample data set and posting exactly how to reproduce this. We don't have your data structure, your data or you application... hard to see what could be wrong.

Also, what does the "refresh" action do ?

I tried to "refresh" P206_SEARCH_RESULT item. It still null with it or without.

That action should not be needed. The "Items to return" will set the value.

What happens if you remove :P206_SEARCH_RESULT from "Items to submit" property?

Nothing changes, still null.

I followed suggestion to reproduce issue on sample data and recreated it on free Apex workspace. At first I couldn't reproduce it, but then randomly found problem cause. Turns out problem is in item. It is of type "Textarea". If you leave everything by default - it works as intended. But if you set it's Height to 1 line - it's stops working! Item's value always null.

This is super weird, looks like a bug.

I tried on apex.oracle.com with textarea of line height 1 and it still sets value correctly - so it might be something else. Happy to take a look if you give me access to a test case where it doesn't work.
